# Is there a quick and economical way to guarantee matrices/vectors with this binary operation in place of addition are associative?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, associativity

I have an algebraic structure that I'll define with the ordered triple $(\{0, 1 \}, \oplus, \times)$ such that the following properties hold:

---

$$ 0 \oplus 0 = 0$$
$$ 1 \oplus 1 = 1 $$
$$0 \oplus 1 = 1 \oplus 0 = 1$$

---

Multiplication given by $\times$ holds as it would normally for the integers $0$ and $1$, and thus needs no distinction.

I already know that $\oplus$ is associative (as can be verified by a few simple computations).

The trick comes from using $\oplus$ in substitution of the usual operation of addition when multiplying vectors by matrices and matrices by other matrices. Both vectors and matrices will only have elements of $\{ 0, 1 \}$ in them.

To wit: given a vector $v \in \{ 0, 1\}^n$ and some square matrix $M \in \{ 0, 1\}^{n \times n}$, I want to define the following as such:

---

$$ (M v)_{i} = \bigoplus_j M_{ij} \times v_j$$
and

$$ (M_1 M_2)_{ij} = \bigoplus_k M_{ik} \times M_{kj}$$

---

Normally we use a base field $\mathbb{F}$ with the usual operation of addition, but for this case I only need two properties to hold for this algebraic structure to serve its purpose:

---

$$ M_1 (M_2 v) = (M_1 M_2)v$$
and
$$ M_1(M_2 M_3) = (M_1 M_2) M_3$$

---

That is, I need to know that I have the usual properties of associativity when multiplying (I have no need for group properties like existence and uniqueness of inverse, though).

Instead of going into the gory details, are there some clean or economical tools out there that quickly and concisely guarantee I have associativity?

Thank you in advance for the help. For those curious: the square matrices that I am using this custom operation in are generally not invertible even when using a field $\mathbb{F}$. Additionally, this question is related to my research, and is not some odd exercise dug out of a textbook.

Comment: Just to confirm that it isn’t a typo, did you really mean $1\oplus 1:=1$ instead of $1\oplus 1:=0$?

Comment: @peek-a-boo Yes, this is not a cyclic group (or a group in general). Closure, associativity and commutativity are properties under $\oplus$, but we don't have (or need for this particular structure) existence and uniqueness of identity or inverse.

Comment: ok, so what’s wrong with repeating the usual proof? It’s not that bad to begin with. Even when dealing with fields, we usually need to get ourselves started by working out some examples in detail, then a whole bunch of other examples follow suit.

Comment: Yes, but I was wondering if it is immediately apparent because our multiplication $\times$ is associative and commutative, and our addition $\oplus$ is associative and commutative that the usual operations of matrix multiplication would have guaranteed associativity.